# Emacs' file extension recognition

Tags: emacs, filenames, open-files

How do I get Emacs to recognize new file extensions? For example if I have a `.c` file and I open it in Emacs, I get the correct syntax highlighting for C, but if I have a `.bob` file format (which I know to be C), how do I tell Emacs to interpret it in the same way as a `.c` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is described on [Emacs Beginner's Howto](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/emacs/emacs-4.html).

With the line

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("README" . text-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

You tell emacs to enter "text-mode" if you open a file which is named README.

with

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.html$" . html-helper-mode) auto-mode-alist))
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.htm$" . html-helper-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

you tell emacs to type "html-helper-mode" if the file is named *.html or *.htm

on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051578/how-to-set-syntax-highlighting-on-for-emacs-files) there is an example, that highligts *.emacs files as lisp.code:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist 
      (append '((".*\\.emacs\\'" . lisp-mode))
              auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: Found the answer myself, but thanks for a more comprehensive answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer :

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.bob" . c-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```